# SetWindowsLong on winproc causes old winproc to be garbage collected

Tags: c#, interop

I have a question that is driving me nuts. I spent a week chasing down this bug, and it may just be I don't understand interop as well as I think. Here it is:

```
 public class User
{
  public const int GWL_WNDPROC = -4;

   [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, User.WindowProc newProc);

   [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr CallWindowProc(IntPtr lpPrevWndFunc, IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    public delegate IntPtr WindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

 }
```

That is my basic User32 wrapper. Now call this:

```
class MyClass
{
  private User.WindowProc proc;

  public void MyMethod()
  {      
    proc = new User.WindowProc(WndProc);

    old_window_proc = User.SetWindowLong(handle,User.GWL_WNDPROC,proc);
  }

}
```

Force garbage collection:

```
   GC.Collect();
   GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

And then call this:

```
User.CallWindowProc(old_window_proc,hWnd,   (uint)message.Msg,message.WParam,message.LParam);
```

I get a **CallbackOnCollectedDelegate ** error. Why does the unmanaged code that exists at the old Winproc pointer get GC'd? If I add this:

```
oldProcHolder = (User.WindowProc)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(old_window_proc, typeof(User.WindowProc));
```

right after the SetWindowLong() it holds on to it and no error.

I guess what I'm not understanding at all is why that old unmanaged code gets eligible for garbage collection? It's driving me nuts. thanks in advance!

Comment: The garbage collector cannot see references held by an unmanaged object.  You need to fix that by storing the delegate object yourself so the GC can see it.  And keep it referenced as long as the window is alive.  Set it back to null and restore the window procedure when you see the WM_DESTROY message.

Comment: That isn't making sense to me. Please bear with me here...

Comment: The old WinProc is unmanaged. Why is the GC touching it?

Comment: sorry keep hitting enter. How does the GC suddenly know that the portion of unmanaged memory that holds the old WinProc is suddenly not being used? What is it even doing touching it? I understand I need a reference to keep something from being GC'd, but what is the GC doing out in unmanaged code? By the way, thanks.

Comment: It is doing *nothing* with unmanaged memory.  That's the problem, it doesn't know that the native window is storing a reference to the callback.  So there's nothing to stop it from collecting the delegate object.

Comment: The one you created with `new User.WindowProc()`

Comment: there is no .NET delegate associated with the old WinProc, it is simply at a point in unmanaged memory. All SetWindowLong did was the the underlying win32 system that the WinProc for the window is now pointing somewhere else and return the address of the previous WinProc. I don't even understand how the .NET framework knows anything about it. There is no reference to it at all in managed memory. Do you see my confusion?

Comment: That one points to the new WinProc we just set, AND there is a reference to it. The OLD WinProc is getting cleaned up. I am aware that if I did this:

Comment: old_window_proc = User.SetWindowLong(handle,User.GWL_WNDPROC,new User.WindowProc(WndProc));

Comment: It would clean up the new one and I'd get the same error. That is why I hold a reference to it.

Comment: I'm just seeing "proc" in the code snippet, I can't tell its scope.

Comment: I don't think I'm being clear and I apologize. The new WinProc I create that is referenced by "proc" is fine. I understand if I didn't reference it, it would GC and it would cause the same error I am asking about. Since I hold a hard reference to it, it is fine. The OLD Winproc that is being pointed to by old_win_proc is collected! There is no delegate to it or anything. I have to create one by Marshaling for it not to garbage collect. Do you see? I'm not having the common problem of not referencing a delegate, I'm having the GC wipe out something ti should even know exists.

Comment: The key to understanding the problem is to look at the code I used to fix it. It is odd.

Comment: As long as you don't improve your code snippet to show how "proc" is stored then I don't have a better guess why the delegate is getting collected.

Comment: proc isn't collected. proc isn't the problem. Sorry if I'm not clear. Look at how I fixed the problem to see what i mean. I enhanced the code.

Comment: You are thinking about this problem:[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428764/callbackoncollecteddelegate-was-detected

Comment: It is still not clear what keeps the MyClass object alive.  Add a destructor to the class and set a breakpoint on it.

Comment: Not an issue. I'm going to repost more code. I'm not getting across what is happening. My fault. Let me remake this entire post by tomorrow with a more code and maybe you can take another look? I haven't seen this anywhere else, and I have it fixed, but I'm clueless as to why the original error was happening. I'

Comment: I'll get better and more detailed code up tonight.

Comment: In fact, I'll give code you can run and see the error.

Answer (score 0):

GetDelegateForFunctionPointer function when used the unmanaged function is converted into a managed code i.e delegate. Since any delegate is a managed code the Garbage collection process runs automatically. Hence GetDelegateForFunctionPointer function is eligible for automatic garbage collection.